# gdb nostop SIGSEGV on a specific thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have a program that purposely segfaults on one threads, but I have a problem that the other thread is segfaulting, I'd like to catch it with GDB, I saw that I can:

```
handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint
```

but I'd like to do that only on the thread that purposely does that.. is it possible?

I'll explain:
I have 2 threads, one thread is segfaulting(and recovers(mprotect read only and then releasing memory)), that works fine, the other thread does something else, but sadly, there is a bug and it is segfaulting, I want to catch that segfault, and not the other ones that occur in the other thread.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the problem a bit more in detail? I read: You have 2 threads, both are running in segfault. You only wants to have the second one respectively only segfauls from a specified thread?

Comment: You can try generating signal other than `SIGSEGV` for the intended thread.

Comment: I can choose what signal I raise using mprotect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, depending on the OS, and I assume linux for my answer and the answer is 'NO'!

Posix exceptions can have a sigmask per thread but only one handler per task. So it is not possible to set different handling for each thread. sigaction will handle it for the complete process. So I see no way for gdb to change this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll explain: I have 2 threads, one thread is segfaulting(and recovers(mprotect read only and then releasing memory)), that works fine, the other thread does something else, but sadly, there is a bug and it is segfaulting, I want to catch that segfault, and not the other ones that occur in the other thread

You have to tell gdb to ignore the first SIGSEGV signal. So after the first sagfault use the `signal 0` command in this thread. Your program will resume execution under gdb and that is that you want. Then it will stop at the second segfault in your second thread and this is what you want to inspect.

```
(gdb) help signal
Continue program with the specified signal.
Usage: signal SIGNAL
The SIGNAL argument is processed the same as the handle command.

An argument of "0" means continue the program without sending it a signal.
This is useful in cases where the program stopped because of a signal,
and you want to resume the program while discarding the signal.
```

So

1. Do not use `handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint`.  Run your program under
   gdb.
2. When it segfaults in the first threead do `signal 0`. Your program
   resumes execution.
3. Then it segfaults in another thread. Now use `backtrace` to see the
   problem.

Or if your two thread are not dependent on each other you can wait in the thread that first segfaulted while another segfault happen. Just do `call sleep(60)` in the first thread as soon as it causes a segfault and wait for another segfault in another thread. Your first thread will wait:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7fde700 (LWP 25744)]
0x000000000040075d in my_thread_func1 (arg=0x0) at my_test_2.cpp:17
17        ptr1 = ptr1 / 0;
(gdb) call sleep(60)
Thread 140737343510272:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff75dd700 (LWP 25745)]
0x00000000004007a3 in my_thread_func2 (arg=0x0) at my_test_2.cpp:27
27        *ptr2 = *ptr2 + 2;
The program received a signal in another thread while
making a function call from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(sleep) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
(gdb)
```

Comment: but the first thread segfaults a LOT, that is part of it's normal operation

Comment: I need him to keep going for the first bug to occur.

Comment: I ended up here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/exception-0xc0000005-from-jni-createjavavm-jvm-dll and thank you very much @user184968, you made my day.