# How can I disable VC++ breaking on a specific win32 exception type for a block of code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm embedding the JVM in my C++ application. When creating the VM, [it generates a SEGV on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258856/49018) to verify CPU/OS features.

This causes my debugger to break on this line of code. I know there is a "break when thrown" list and I can disable this exception type, but I still want it to break on legitimate segfaults, just not this one.

Is there a pragma or something I can use to tell VC++ to not catch `Access Violation`s for a line of code? Or is there some other kind of solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `__try {...} __except()` statement.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396