# JNI_CreateJavaVm segmentation fault

Tags: java, c++, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I am compiling my code using MinGW_64 via Eclipse (Mars 2). When I run the release version of the code through Eclipse (Run As) the JVM is created as expected (the return value is zero) but when I debug using Eclipse (Debug As) and step over the JNI_CreateJavaVM line i get a segmentation fault which, after I step through, still get a return value of zero.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000f0103b4 in ?? ()

Can someone explain why this happens?

Here is the code (be sure to include the jni.h and jni_md.h files and link in the jvm libraray - I am using Java jdk 1.8.0_101).

```
/*
 * jnitest.c
 */
#include "jni.h"
JNIEnv* create_vm()
{
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    long result=JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
    printf("here is the result %li", result);
    return env;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm();
}
```

Comment: The only issue I see with your code is that you do not initialize the `extraInfo` member of your option, but that seems typical of the examples I find.  In any case, I don't think you can read anything into the return value following a segfault.

Comment: My only thought is that it might be something wrong with how the runtime is configured (i.e., you compiled against one library but are using another at runtime which generates the segmentation fault).

Comment: Thanks John and Robert. @RobertPrevost, Java 1.8 64 bit is the only Java I have on my computer - how can I tell what libraries are being used during run time version vs when I compile? BTW I am compiling and running in Eclipse.

Comment: This is an expected behavior. The VM intentionally generates SEGV on start up and the handles it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/exception-0xc0000005-from-jni-createjavavm-jvm-dll). When you run a program in debug mode, the signal handler is overriden by Eclipse debugger.