# Process termination when invoking "JNI_CreateJavaVM"?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-8, jvm

I have a .dll which loads the jvm of different Java versions by invoking the "JNI_CreateJavaVM".

The code:

```
(...)
JavaVMInitArgs jvmArgs;
std::vector<JavaVMOption> jvmOptions;

for (const std::string &str : options) {
    JavaVMOption option;
    option.extraInfo = nullptr;
    option.optionString = (char *)str.c_str();
    jvmOptions.push_back(option);
}

jvmArgs.nOptions = jvmOptions.size();
jvmArgs.options = &jvmOptions.front();
jvmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
jvmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

std::string jvmPath = m_jdkProvider->getPathToJvmDll();
auto h = os_load_library(jvmPath.c_str());

if (h == nullptr) {
    m_lastError = "Can not load " + jvmPath;
    return false;
}

auto JNI_CreateJavaVM = (JNI_CreateJavaVMType)os_get_proc_address(h, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

if (JNI_CreateJavaVM == nullptr) {
    m_lastError = "failed to create Java VM. JNI_CreateJavaVM is not found in library " + jvmPath;
    return false;
}
MessageBox(NULL, "I'm before JNI_CreateJavaVM", "Info", MB_OK);

JNIEnv *env;
int res;

CLrJavaToCppException ex;
ex.Enable();
try {
    res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&m_jvm, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), &jvmArgs);
}
catch (std::exception ex) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "I'm in JNI_CreateJavaVM exception", "Info", MB_OK);
}

MessageBox(NULL, "I'm after JNI_CreateJavaVM", "Info", MB_OK);

if (res < 0) {
(...)
```

This dll can be invoked by two different processes: one written in C++ and one in C#.

When invoking a **jvm of Java 8**, the process written in **C++ terminates** unexpectedly, while the one in **C# continues running**.

I know that JNI intentionally throws the 0xC0000005 exception [for different purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/exception-0xc0000005-from-jni-createjavavm-jvm-dll), but it's also handled at that level.

I'm not sure if the process termination is cased by this exception, but I tried catching the exception in different ways:

1. Building the project with  **(/EHa)** - no effect.
2. Using `_se_translator_function` - was able to catch only the exception in the C#-type process
3. ```
   int res;
   __try {
       res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&m_jvm, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), &jvmArgs);
   }
   __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
       MessageBox(NULL, "I'm in JNI_CreateJavaVM exception", "Info", MB_OK);
   }
   ```

   but without effect for none of the processes.

Can someone suggest something?