# Using address sanitizer with surefire

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to build shared library with `JNI` functions with GCC's address sanitizer to use in tests. Since jvm itself is not built with adress sinitizer there is a LD_PRELOAD trick to make it work as discribed in this [issue](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/679).

So I configured `maven-surefire-plugin` as follows:

```
<configuration>
     <forkMode>always</forkMode>
     <environmentVariables>
           <LD_PRELOAD>/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4.0.0</LD_PRELOAD>
     </environmentVariables>
</configuration>
```

But `mvn clean install` still crashes with SEGV as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==1225==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000
```

failing the build. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258856/2786156) I concluded that because of JVM uses signals for its own purpose such SEGV caused by reading on zero address is expected.

Is there a way to work around this? Maybe it is safe to simply ignore `SEGV` when running with sanitizers similar to when debugging JVM with `gdb`?

Comment: You can try running under `export ASAN_OPTIONS=handle_segv=0`. If this does not help we'll need a gdb stacktrace (you'll likely need symbols for `libasan.so`).