# JVM is not recognizing my available memory

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory, ram

I have a Ubuntu server (20.04) with 4GB RAM. After starting some applications it have 2.5GB of available RAM. When I try to start a java application using a Heap Size of 1GB(-Xms1g -Xmx1g) it wont start and log the following error

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to
> continue. Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824
> bytes for committing reserved memory.

If I try to lower the heap sizes to 512m or lower it will start but after a couple of minutes the service stop with similar error even if I have half of the memory available.
It look like JVM is not using/recognizing all the available memory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413580/why-the-operating-system-says-it-cant-allocate-memory-to-jvm-when-it-has-enough)? Show the result of `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory vm.overcommit_ratio` and `cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot @apangin

Comment: Good. I'm closing the question as duplicate then.

Answer (score 0):

You can be potentially impacted by [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187709); there are 2 possible workarounds there (per ticket):

1. Disable compressed Oops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops) with slight performance penalty. This will instruct JVM to run without the Compressed Oops feature and it would not try to fit the Java Heap in the first 4GB of heap
2. Keep the CompressedOops and set the base of the Java Heap with the JVM option -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=n to specify the address where the Java Heap should start from set it to a higher address so that there is enough room available for the native mallocs