# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed despite having enough available memory

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, linux-kernel, jvm

#### Introduction

I've got a couple of Docker services running on a VM. Most of them are containerized Java applications, but there are other containers too (e.g. a Postgres database).

After deploying some updated Docker images to the VM, multiple services start to suffer from native memory allocation failures in some minutes after the new images are deployed.

There is no limit on the memory usage of the containers, I only restrict the heap size of the Java processes by setting the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` values to some constant value.

The behavior was very similar on the whole fleet of (40+) VMs, so it is not related to a single potentially corrupt machine.

#### A JVM process for example (output truncated)

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007fe7f5985000, 65536, 1) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Can not save log file, dump to screen..
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Unscaled Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 4GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 4GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2791), pid=83, tid=0x00007fe7eef2e700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_382-b05) (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.382-b05 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/jboss/core or core.83
#
...
heap address: 0x00000000e0000000, size: 512 MB, Compressed Oops mode: 32-bit
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000100000000
...

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -D[Standalone] -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/gc -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties 
java_command: /opt/jboss/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
java_class_path (initial): /opt/jboss/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
...
OS:CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

uname:Linux 3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 13 14:19:20 UTC 2023 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC infinity, NOFILE 3000, AS infinity
load average:1.51 1.83 2.82

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       65808112 kB
MemFree:        10857340 kB
MemAvailable:   34898064 kB
Buffers:            1232 kB
Cached:         27654720 kB
SwapCached:          476 kB
Active:         39339992 kB
Inactive:       12784464 kB
Active(anon):   26140628 kB
Inactive(anon):  2754108 kB
Active(file):   13199364 kB
Inactive(file): 10030356 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       6291452 kB
SwapFree:        6284540 kB
Dirty:              1744 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      24468628 kB
Mapped:          1565020 kB
Shmem:           4426112 kB
Slab:            1677728 kB
SReclaimable:    1343136 kB
SUnreclaim:       334592 kB
KernelStack:       49104 kB
PageTables:       133412 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    68809156 kB
Committed_AS:   68797848 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      255572 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359339004 kB
Percpu:             4768 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    407552 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      159616 kB
DirectMap2M:    13471744 kB
DirectMap1G:    55574528 kB

container (cgroup) information:
container_type: cgroupv1
cpu_cpuset_cpus: 0-5
cpu_memory_nodes: 0
active_processor_count: 6
cpu_quota: -1
cpu_period: 100000
cpu_shares: -1
memory_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_and_swap_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_soft_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_usage_in_bytes: 916889600
memory_max_usage_in_bytes: 923705344
```

**My interpretation:** the JVM fails to allocate ~65 KB of memory with mmap, despite the ~35 GB of available memory (MemAvailable).

#### The Postgres 12 process (output truncated)

```
2023-10-24 15:26:29.512 UTC 1343 @ from  [vxid:112/0 txid:0] [] DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 3712 in memory context "dynahash".
TopMemoryContext: 134232 total in 7 blocks; 28312 free (7 chunks); 105920 used
  ...
Grand total: 1939816 bytes in 276 blocks; 573888 free (221 chunks); 1365928 used
```

#### Question

With other monitoring tools I was able to cross check that there should be more than enough available memory (>30GB), so I can't understand, why mmap fails. The Docker services, which had been running before my deployment, have used much more RAM than the new ones, and they had zero out of memory errors. What is the detail, which I oversee? What parameter do I have to change to fix the out of memory errors?

#### What I have tried

To adhere to the [official Postgres recommendations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT) (which is also a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55473566/21797336)) I have set the following sysctl properties:

```
vm.overcommit_memory=2
vm.overcommit_ratio=95
```

#### System info

- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
- Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_382-b05)
- Postgres Docker image: 12.6-alpine

#### UPDATE: Solution

As [@Henrique de Sousa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420441/henrique-de-sousa) pointed out the reason for the failing mmap allocations was the committed memory: the Committed_AS metric has almost reached the CommitLimit (in `/proc/meminfo`), because of which the kernel denied the mmap requests (this is the documented behavior, when `vm.overcommit_memory=2`).

```
CommitLimit:    68809156 kB
Committed_AS:   68797848 kB
```

After this realization it all started to make sense, and by putting a [memory limit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#memory) on every container (especially on the naughty Postgres one, which has a tendency to commit all committable memory) we were able to fix the failing mmap calls.

Comment: Find out what is eating the memory on your container and make it use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [Why the operating system says it can't allocate memory to jvm when it has enough memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413580/why-the-operating-system-says-it-cant-allocate-memory-to-jvm-when-it-has-enough)

As in the beforehand question, the amount of currently allocated memory on the system has almost reached the limit:

```
CommitLimit:    68809156 kB
Committed_AS:   68797848 kB
```

Solution presented was to either:

1. enable heuristic overcommit handling:

`sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=0`

2. increase overcommit ratio:

`sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=100`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That may cause the OOM killer to crash PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Henrique de Sousa: The observation is correct, the committed memory seems to be the issue. I would try to find a different solution as Laurenz Albe suggested, the vm.overcommit_memory=2 is a recommended value by the [official Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT). I will try to change the config of the other apps to commit to less memory.