# JNI_CreateJavaVM function method does not work and cannot be debugged

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

JNI_CreateJavaVM function method does not work and cannot be debugged.

- The development environment is win10 x64, jdk version is 1.8
- Visual studio 2017 Community Edition Writing a C++ project

---

I am learning about JNI. I am trying to run `The Invocation API`. The following URL is an example of the official website documentation.
 Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#creating_the_vm)!

I built the project and added a project dependency that contains jvm.lib. And I put jvm.dll in the project directory. I successfully run this program.

### `Main.test()` is a method of print `hello world`. But the program exits when executing JNI_CreateJavaVM, the console shows that the return value is 1.

I can't get into debugging, I don't know what happened.

```cpp
#include <jni.h>


int main() {
    printf("begin..........\n");
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    char optionString[] = "-Djava.class.path =D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191/lib/";
    options[0].optionString = optionString;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    /* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
     * pointer in env */

    int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    printf("result=%d", res);
    delete options;
    /* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
    /* We are done. */
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect this jvm can be called, but it is forced to exit when the program is executed to `int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
Where am I wrong? Why is it not working?

Exit screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ejgw.png)

jvm.dll location
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhOAp.png)

jvm.lib  linker additional library directories
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfVgD.png)

jvm.lib  linker  additional Dependencies
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrOC4.png)

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  It sits in its bedroom all day and refuses to get a job?

Comment: How did you determine that it crashes at the JNI_CreateJavaVM statement instead of, say, the `CallStaticVoidMethod` invocation? You cannot trust that `printf` as it does not flush its buffer to your console without a newline.

Comment: I ran the project in debug mode, and I gradually debugged the program, but when the program executed to the JNI_CreateJavaVM method, the entire process crashed and exited, and the following statements were not executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Classpath**

There is a space between key and equal sign. The space must be removed.

```
char optionString[] = "-Djava.class.path =D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191/lib/";
```

**Classpath value**

The java.class.path value must point to the base directory where your compiled .class files are located.

It looks like you're not using a package name, then it's the directory where Main.class is located, so probably it should look something like this:

```
char optionString[] = "-Djava.class.path=c:/Users/name/MyJavaPrograms/classes";
```

**Access violation**

> SEGV (or exception 0xC0000005) is also generated intentionally on JVM startup to verify certain CPU/OS features.

see this fine answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258856

In Visual Studio, when the exception dialog is shown, simply turn off that it breaks there. This will prevent you from seeing it again the next time you start the program again.

**Java**

Just for the sake of completeness: the Java method should look like this:

```
public class Main {

public static void test(int num) {
    System.out.println("Java: test called with '" + num + "'");
}

...
```

**Visual Studio Configuration**

The jvm.dll needs to be found. In Visual Studio under Configuration Properties/Debugging/Environment add  PATH=%PATH%;<path-to-jdk>\bin\server

For later deployment you could think about putting the whole JRE into a subfolder of your application and reference it with a relative path.

**Demo**

Finally a brief demo (added a \n here `printf("result=%d\n", res);` to have a separate line):

[image: Demo]

Comment: First, I have removed this space. For the first time, I tried to point java.class.path to the jdk installation path, and it still stopped running. The second time, I pointed java.class.path to the compiled directory of the Main class, and it stopped running. It seems that my exception is 0x001 is not 0xc00005, your demo can not be opened, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is my dependency library and dynamic link library not in the right position? Or am I adding a part less? I uploaded my environment information in the question, you can look

Comment: You should not just copy a small part of the Java runtime. If you want to deploy the app at some point in time you could put the JRE into a subfolder of the application.

Comment: In Visual Studio under Configuration Properties/Debugging/Environment add PATH=%PATH%;<path-to-jdk>\bin\server. I've updated the answer.