# Exception 0xC0000005 in jvm.dll when creating an instance via JNI NewObject

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am writing [a plug-in](https://github.com/hoehermann/purple-signal) for an existing application. Implementation language is C. However, the actual functionality is implemented in Java. For this reason, I am using [Java Native Interface (JNI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) to create a JVM instance from within C. I can find the appropriate Java class and create an instance. This is what the code looks like:

```
login(uintptr_t connection, const char* username, …) {
    …
    jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ps->class, "<init>", "(JLjava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring jusername = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, username);
    jobject instance = (*env)->NewObject(env, ps->class, constructor, connection, jusername);
```

Everything works just fine.

On Linux.

On Windows, it is a complete mess. As soon as I try to create an instance of the Java class, it throws a

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0813751f, pid=8, tid=0x00000009
```

. More details are written to a log file, but the stack trace is not helpful other than pointing to somewhere in the jvm.dll. Stepping through with a debugger has not been insightful. Note this is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/).

Comment: One of the parameters is incorrect. There's not enough information here to say more.

Comment: @user207421 I added the JNI type signature. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days, I figured it out.

The constructor I am invoking expects a parameter. The type is `long` (Java) aka `J` (JNI Type Signature) aka `jlong` (corresponing C type). A C `uintptr_t` is compatible with a `jlong`.

On Linux, my `uintptr_t` is 8 bytes long, since I am in a amd64 environment with 64 bit applications. For Windows, the application was build in 32 bit. As a result `uintptr_t` is only 4 bytes long, but the JVM still expect a 8 byte `jlong`. However, `NewObject` is a variadic function, automatic promotion does not happen and type safety is not guaranteed.

```
login(uintptr_t connection, const char* username, …) {
    …
    jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ps->class, "<init>", "(JLjava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring jusername = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, username);
    jlong jconnection = connection;
    jobject instance = (*env)->NewObject(env, ps->class, constructor, jconnection, jusername);
```

A simple cast to the correct type was the solution. I expect this pitfall to exist with `CallVoidMethod` or any of the `Call*Method` [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html), too.