# LoadVM Java VM with JNI - access violation

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-xe7

I have problem with loading Java VM. When I do LoadVM program gives access violation. On other computer it works fine. Here is some code that works but not on my machine:

```
uses jni;
var

Options: array [0..1] of JavaVMOption;
VM_args: JavaVMInitArgs;
ErrCode: Integer;
AJavaVM: TJavaVM;
AJavaEnvMain: TJNIEnv;
JrePath, ProgramPath, LibPath, File1, File2: string;

begin

  ProgramPath := 'd:\testjava\exe\';
  JrePath := ProgramPath + 'JRE\bin\client\';
  LibPath := ProgramPath + 'JRE\lib\ext\';   

   File1 := LibPath + 'file1.jar';
   File2 := LibPath + 'file2.jar';

  AJavaVM := TJavaVM.Create(JNI_VERSION_1_8, JrePath + 'jvm.dll');

   FillChar(Options, SizeOf(Options), #0);

   Options[0].optionString := PAnsiChar(AnsiString('-D java.class.path=' + File1 + ';' + File2));

   VM_args.version := JNI_VERSION_1_8;
   VM_args.Options := @Options;
   VM_args.nOptions := 1;
   ErrCode := AJavaVM.LoadVM(VM_args); **//access violation**

   if ErrCode < 0 then
   raise Exception.CreateFmt('Initialization error JVM, błąd %d.', [ErrCode]);
```

Comment: Maybe related / already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/exception-0xc0000005-from-jni-createjavavm-jvm-dll

Comment: When you see the AV, are you running inside the debugger? Does the AV actually reach your code? If not, then don't worry about it.

Comment: I'm running inside the debugger. That AV causes not working Java VM. So I can't go further.